# Sorting most descending date at top TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, nsdate, cell

**Situation**

I have a tableview with scheduled local notifications stored in cells, containing a title, date, UUID and mood. They repeat weekly from the day the users chooses and works perfectly fine. I have successfully sorted the cells so that the most descending (soonest) notification is at the top of the table view through this line of code in the `refreshList()`:

```
dqItems.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
```

**Problem**

However, when a notification has been fired and is overdue, 7 days is being added to its date through the `if (dqItem.isOverdue)` function. This works - 7 days is added to the date. But the tableview doesn't re-sort the cells - the notification cell which has been rescheduled with 7 days is still at the top! Despite the fact that there are other notifications with more descending dates scheduled. (See image for example)

This is extremely frustrating and I can't managed to find a solution. Here comes a snippet from the `Table View Controller` file.

```
//Outlets
var dqItems: [DQItem] = []
var MoodString = String()

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    refreshList()
}

func refreshList() {

    dqItems = DQList.sharedInstance.allItems()

        dqItems.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dqItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dqCell", for: indexPath) // retrieve the prototype cell (subtitle style)
    var dqItem = dqItems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as DQItem
    cell.textLabel?.text = dqItem.title as String!

    if (dqItem.isOverdue)
    { // the current time is later than the to-do item's date

        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: dqItem.date)!
        dqItem.date = newDate
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE's' 'at' HH:mm"
        print("newdate", newDate) //seven days is added!
        print("dqItem.d", dqItem.date) //same here

       viewDidAppear(true) //reload the view to re-sort the cells??? = not working

    }

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: dqItem.date as Date)

    return cell
}//End of cellforrowatindexPath
```

The DQItem, where the struct is.

```
 import UIKit

 struct DQItem {

  var title: String
  var date: Date
  var UUID: String
  var mood: String

init(date: Date, title: String, UUID: String, mood: String) { 

    self.date = date
    self.title = title
    self.UUID = UUID
    self.mood = mood

}

 //Overdue function
 var isOverdue: Bool {

     return (Date().compare(self.date) == .orderedDescending) // date is earlier than current date
}



}
```

Appreciate all help trying to solve this silly problem!

[image: Example: "Today" comes after "Next Thursday" despite the fact it's more descending]

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `viewDidAppear`.  That method is supposed to only be called by the `UIKit`.  Just call your own refresh code instead.

(Even if calling view state methods was a good idea, you would be calling the wrong one since you implemented `viewWillAppear` to do your initial refresh.)

EDIT:
For the problem of how to change your table ordering while the table is being updated, you need to wait until the current update is finished.  One way to do that would be to submit the next reload request to the main queue.  Since the main queue is serial, that would delay it until current work finishes.

Try moving the table reordering into its own method...

```
func orderTable() {
    dqItems.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

...then call it via GCD instead of calling the view lifecycle method.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    orderTable()
}
```

That's the simple version.  If you want to be more efficient, you can look into ways to make sure the `orderTable` call only happens once per reload.

Comment: Tried to add the dqItems.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date}) into the function instead of the viewWillAppear - no change. Please see my update of the question for a clearer explanation of the problem. Thank you @philipMills

Comment: Do you also call `reloadData`?

Comment: Yes, but it creates a loop of the function then... This confirms the fact that the code fails to use the new 7 days+ `dqItem.Date` and replace the old one which has already fired. Is there a way to send the overdue `Table View Cell` to the bottom of the `Table View`? It would also solve my problem. @philipMills

Comment: Of course...sorry about that!  One way might be to put the sort and reload into a block and dispatch it asynchronously to the main queue.  That should get rid of the loop problem.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how you mean through answering the question once again? I'm new to programming so would really appreciate all your help :) @philipMills

Comment: @Mate - Updated the answer.

Comment: @philipmills tried your updated answer without result - the `newDate` is added to the `dqItem` but it's not updated. Extremely weird, the old "overdue" date is still kept instead of the new one. Is there a way of forcing the `dqItem` to adapt the new date? I've also been looking into some other potential options, how about `tableview.beginupdates()`? Could it help? Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: I don't understand "the newDate is added to the dqItem but it's not updated".  Since a `DQItem` only has one date, doesn't it have to be either the new one or the old one?  I wonder if this is related to `struct`...if you make `DQItem` a class, does the update work better?

Comment: When I print the `dqItem.date` in the console it has the same date as the newDate - 7 days into the future. BUT, the `Table View` doesn't update this, since the overdue cell still is at the top (which most be caused by the old and overdue date which is still there!). Tried making `DQItem` into a class of a `NSObject`, no success. How about using `willChangeValue` or another similar method? I can't understand why it won't update at all.

Comment: @philipMills I think I have come up with a potenial solution lying in the sorting, please take a look at my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796162/sort-dates-with-closets-to-now-first