# Sort dates with closets to now first and past at the bottom

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, date

I have a tableview in which there are multiple date. I need to sort the dates so that the most descending date is at the top (`(indexPath.row == 0)`) and the past dates needs to be at the bottom (`(indexPath.row == ´lastRows´)`) and in between the other upcoming dates.

I have been looking around without finding a proper solution. The following code only displays the earliest date first - failing to put the past dates at the bottom as I desire. (see picture for clearer example of the problem, the sort I want:

- Upcoming One
- Upcoming 2
- Past Date 
  )

  `dqItems.sort(by: {$0.date < $1.date})`

Is there a way of accomplishing this? Alternatively pushing a date (and its cell) to the bottom of the table view when the date becomes the past?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "less than" sign to "greater than":

```
dqItems.sort(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can reverse the array with the reverse() function.

Comment: @kkoltzau That could work, but it's needless complexity.

Comment: That would work if I wanted to put the "Upcoming 2" at the top and the past dates and the bottom. But what I'm trying to do is to get "Upcoming 1" followed by "Upcoming 2" and "Past Date" at the bottom, since it's been in the past tense. @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: How would that look like? See my updated answer for clearer example of the problem. Thank you @kkoltzau

Comment: I would object to that design, as it would be pretty unintuitive what's going on. Perhaps make separate sections in your tableview, one for the future, one for the past. If you insist on this though, split the list, sort each however you like, join them back together.

Comment: Your idea of creating two different sections sounds great. Would I then be able to "send" a date, once it's in the past to the "bottom section" from the "top section?" Thanks for your help @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: Of course, just delete it from one sectioion and add it to the other

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use .sort, use .sorted to get a sorted copy. Then search the sorted copy to find where the current time belongs. Use that index to make a couple of slices and copy the slices where you want them (back in the original array).